# Locale.IsoCountryCode doesn't exist in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

The `Locale.IsoCountryCode` method doesn't exist when attempting to use it in Android Studio.  Why?

I made sure that I'm using the latest Android Studio and Java 17 yet, yet the method is still unavailable.  Maybe I'm not understanding the proper why of ensuring Android Studio and Java versions are linked properly.  I'm trying to use the `IsoCountryCode` method to get 3 letter country codes for a currency exchange rate API.

Comment: Are you looking for [`getISO3Language()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Locale#getiso3language)?

Comment: From the JDK only the compiler is used, the Java runtime library not, Android has it's own API and if you look at it you will see that it does not contain `IsoCountryCode` https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale not sure if there is a compatibility library that extends Android by this property. But that would be a project specific extension. In the Android API it is not included.

Answer (score 0):

For getting country code, you can use property `country`, as described in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
String countryCode = myLocale.getCountry();
```